# Track memory used by WCF Application hosted in IIS?

Tags: .net, wcf, memory-management, iis-7, performancecounter

**Hi,**

I know about the performance counters for the serviceModel namespace bot how do I track the memmory used by a specific WCF application hosted in IIS with performance counters?

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS deployed WCF services run in the w3wp.exe process, use the memory counters for this process.